# How to implement a validator for a spin box to check if (n mod k == 0)?

Tags: c++, qt, validation, qt5, qspinbox

I have a `QSpinBox` that takes `int`s, with a certain minimum and maximum values set. I need to set a filter on the spin box to allow only numbers divisible by a certain other integer number. This seems to be the right task for a `QIntValidator`. But I don't understand:

- when to return `Intermediate` and when `Acceptable`, given that the number may have 2 to 4 digits, and until the number is input fully by the user, no decision can be made
- how to handle setting the minimum and maximum values: currently, I set them using `setMinimumValue()` and `setMaximumValue()` respectively; what does installing a validator change in this regard?

The number can be both negative and positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QSpinBox` has its own implementation of `validate` method inherited from its base class `QAbstractSpinBox`. If you want to customize the behaviour of this method, for example by using `QIntValidator`, you need to subclass `QSpinBox` and reimplement the `validate` method accordingly in your subclass.

The logics you require - "allow only numbers divisible by a certain other integer number" - is beyond the range of `QIntValidator`'s capabilities. All it can do is to say whether the given string can be converted to integer within a specified range - or whether the given string can be extended to become convertable to such an integer (`Intermediate` state).

I think you could use `QIntValidator` as a preprocessor inside your `QSpinBox` subclass' `validate` method implementation: you call `QIntValidator::validate` first and if it returns the `Invalid` state, so does your method. But if it returns `Intermediate` or `Acceptable`, you need to proceed on your own:

1. Take the input string and try to convert it into an integer -
   probably `QString::toInt` should suffice.
2. Encode your own logics which looks at the received integer and determines whether it is divisible by a certain other integer. If yes, your method returns `Acceptable` state. If not, you need to somehow figure out whether this integer can be "extended" to become acceptable. For example, you say the number can be 2 to 4 characters long - that means that at least a subset of 1, 2 and 3-digits integers could be extended to become acceptable. If the processed integer belongs to such a subset, your method should return `Intermediate`, otherwise it should return `Invalid`.

About min/max values: `QSpinBox`'s `setMinimum` and `setMaximum` methods define the range which `QSpinBox::validate` uses to check the input. If you follow my suggestion of using `QIntValidator` in the beginning of `validate` method of your `QSpinBox` subclass, you should set these minimum and maximum values to `QIntValidator`'s bottom and top properties respectively:

```
class MySpinBox: public QSpinBox
{
    <...>
};

QValidator::State MySpinBox::validate(QString &text, int &pos) const
{
    QIntValidator validator;
    validator.setBottom(minimum());
    validator.setTop(maximum());
    QValidator::State state = validator.validate(text, pos);
    if (state == QValidator::Invalid) {
        return state;
    }

    <...> // Otherwise proceed with your own logics
}
```